# Object literal may only specify known properties, and ''app-id'' does not exist in type 'Headers'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Below is my code to get data from remote server.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

const URL = process.env.REACT_APP_URL;
const API = process.env.REACT_APP_API;
const APPID = process.env.REACT_APP_APPID;

const PageTitle = styled(Typography)({
    fontSize: '30px',
    marginBottom: '20px',
});

const SearchField = styled(TextField)({
    width: '100%',
});

export default function Search() {
    const [filterableData, setfilterableData] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            const response = await fetch(`${URL}${API}`, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'app-id': APPID,
                },
            });         const data = await response.json();
            console.log(data);
        }
        fetchData();
    });

    const search = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target.value);
    };

    return (
        <Container maxWidth="lg">
            <PageTitle>Search</PageTitle>
            <SearchField
                id="outlined-search"
                label="Enter search query"
                type="search"
                onChange={search}
            />
        </Container>
    );
}
```

It throws below error.

```
Type '{ 'app-id': string | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'HeadersInit | undefined'.
  Type '{ 'app-id': string | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.  TS2322

    26 |            const response = await fetch(`${URL}${API}`, {
    27 |                method: 'GET',
  > 28 |                headers: {
       |                ^
    29 |                    'app-id': APPID,
    30 |                },
    31 |            });
```

Searched over the internet and the solutions I got was related to making interface etc. But none of those solutions worked for me. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: where fetch is coming from? If ```window.fetch```, syntax is incomplete, shoud be something like ```fetch(url, {method:'get', headers:{...}})```. however, to strong typing http requests, I would rather go with librairies like axios or react-query if this is in React components. they provide strong and easy way to type requests, response, body and params

Comment: @Jerome just updated my post. The error is different now.

Comment: @Jerome even axios is throwing above error. There is some kind of issue with typescript.

Comment: try creating `new Headers()` and putting `app-id` into it. use its reference instead json schema

Comment: @benjaminc that also throws an error `Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.  TS2345

    25 |   async function fetchData() {
    26 |    const headers: HeadersInit = new Headers();
  > 27 |    headers.set('app-id', ID);
       |                          ^
 `

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use `Headers` class

```js
const headers = new Headers();
if(APPID) {
  headers.set('app-ip', APPID);
}


async function fetchData() {
  const response = await fetch(`${URL}${API}`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers
});
```

Comment: With that it gives me this error `Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.  TS2345

    11 | const headers: HeadersInit = new Headers();
  > 12 | headers.set('app-id', ID);
       |                       ^

 `

Comment: @Om3ga, could you try the updated variant?

Answer (score 0):

```
headers: {
  'app-id': APPID as string,
},
```

above solved my problem.

Comment: this is not a good practice, as environment varaibles could be undefined. So below

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bug in `lib.dom.d.ts`, but you still have some choices to figure it out.

- Type assertion.

```js
    fetch({
        headers: {'app-id': APPID} as Headers
    })
```

- Ignore it.

```js
    fetch({
      // @ts-ignore
      headers: {'app-id': APPID}
    })
```

- Use Headers Api.

  ```
  fetch({
      headers: new Headers({'app-id': APPID}) 
    })
  ```

if you want to make older browsers compatible, you should import a `Headers` polyfill first.
Note that code below has not been tested.

```
  (function(){
    if(typeof Headers !== 'function') {
      window.Headers = function(headers: Record<string, string>){return headers}
    }
  })()
```

For the solutions listed above, I recommend type assertions the most.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that APPID can be undefined as this is an enviroment variable. You should test is is not undefined or force it using  `!` if you are sure it is defined (i.e. tested before the function is called)

```
const url = process.env.REACT_APP_URL;
const API = process.env.REACT_APP_API;
const APPID = process.env.REACT_APP_APPID;


async function fetchData():Promise<void> {
  const response = await fetch(`${url}${API}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
          'app-id': APPID ?APPID:"", // or 'app_id':APPID!
      },
  });         const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
}
fetchData();
```